# Jolt Spec - Map a field within an array conditionally based on an outer field

Tags: json, transform, jolt

I want to conditionally map fields within an array based on the value of a field that's outside the array.

- If `message.conditionCode` is "AA", then map `data[].field1` to `data[].conditionalField`
- If `message.conditionCode` is "BB", then map `data[].field2` to `data[].conditionalField`

Also the conditionCode itself needs to be mapped to `message.conditionCd`.

I tried traversing back from within data[] to message node and check conditionCode but not sure how to travel back inside the data[].

Current Spec does not have this conditional mapping:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "event": {
        "id": "event.id"
      },
      "message": {
        "id": "message.idNbr",
        "conditionCode": "message.conditionCd",
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "id": "message.data[&1].idNbr",
            "field3": "message.data[&1].directField"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Input JSON 1:

```json
{
  "event": {
    "id": "12345678"
  },
  "message": {
    "id": "1001",
    "conditionCode": "AA",
    "location": "US",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "field3": "value3"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "field1": "value4",
        "field2": "value5",
        "field3": "value6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output JSON 1:

```json
{
  "event": {
    "id": "12345678"
  },
  "message": {
    "idNbr": "1001",
    "conditionCd": "AA",
    "data": [
      {
        "idNbr": "1",
        "directField": "value3",
        "conditionalField": "value1"
      },
      {
        "idNbr": "2",
        "directField": "value6",
        "conditionalField": "value4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Input JSON 2:

```json
{
  "event": {
    "id": "12345678"
  },
  "message": {
    "id": "1001",
    "conditionCode": "BB",
    "location": "US",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "field3": "value3"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "field1": "value4",
        "field2": "value5",
        "field3": "value6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Output JSON 2:

```json
{
  "event": {
    "id": "12345678"
  },
  "message": {
    "idNbr": "1001",
    "conditionCd": "BB",
    "data": [
      {
        "idNbr": "1",
        "directField": "value3",
        "conditionalField": "value2"
      },
      {
        "idNbr": "2",
        "directField": "value6",
        "conditionalField": "value5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "event": {
        "id": "event.&"
      },
      "message": {
        "id": "&1.&Nbr",
        "conditionCode": "&1.conditionCd",
        "data": {
          "*": {
            "id": "&3.&2[&1].&Nbr",
            "field3": "&3.&2[&1].directField",
            "@2,conditionCode": {// bring the value of conditionCode after going two levels up the tree
              "AA": { "@2,field1": "&5.&4[&3].conditionalField" },
              "BB": { "@2,field2": "&5.&4[&3].conditionalField" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where path lookup wildcard & is used where needed instead of repeating the literals `id`, `data`, `message`